# Automatize automatizing login scripts

Tags: http, curl

So, there are a lot of questions about automatizing login to various web pages.
To do it, I usually log in to them manually and then analyzing request and response, so I can create my own piece of code.
I am looking for way to automatize both request analysis and generating this piece of script (can be curl, from working curl it's not hard to develop solution in any programming language).

Sure, there are some things like CSRF tokens and attachments, that needs to be considered.

What can be done about it?

EDIT: This is what I have been using up to now:

public class FormAnalyzer
{
    private FormAnalyzer() {}

```
@SneakyThrows
public static void analyzeForms(String website)
{
    Jsoup
        .parse(new URL(website), 600000)
        .getElementsByTag("form")
        .forEach(FormAnalyzer::analyzeForm);
}

private static void analyzeForm(Element form)
{
    System.out.println(form.attributes().asList());

    form.getElementsByTag("input")
        .stream()
        .map(FormAnalyzer::inputToString)
        .reduce((s, s2) -> s + s2)
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
}

private static String inputToString(Element input)
{
    String name = input.attr("name");
    String type = input.attr("type").toUpperCase();
    String value = input.attr("value");

    return (name.isEmpty() ? type : name) + "=" + value + "\n";
}
```

however, it has troubles with javascript, CSRF tokens and attachments.

Comment: And you don't try any code? And wait for someone do everything and give code for you? Why?

Comment: I wanted to keep this question language-adherent but if You want it - here You go. Also, it's always wise to ask before coding, as maybe similar solution already exists - DRY.